# ошибка в qiwi API при переводе на банковскую карту

Tags: php, api, qiwi

Пытаюсь отправить деньги на русскую VISA

```
$option = [
  'id' => 1000*strtotime('now'),
  'fields' => ['account' => '42767************'],
  'sum' => ['amount' => 100, 'currency' => '643'],
  'paymentMethod' => ['type' => 'Account', 'accountId' => '643'],
];  
$token_qiwi = "**************";             
$zapros = curl_init();
$arr[CURLOPT_URL] = 'https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/1963/payments';
$arr[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = TRUE;
$arr[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 10;
$arr[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array("Accept: application/json", "Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ".$token_qiwi);
$arr[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE;
$arr[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = json_encode($option);
curl_setopt_array($zapros, $arr);
echo curl_exec($zapros);    
curl_close($zapros);
```

пишет:
{"message":"Json validation error List((obj.id,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray()))))"}

Подскажите что я делаю не так? уже всю документацию прочел вдоль и попрек

у токена все разрешения

Comment: json_encode($option, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)

Answer (score 0):

оказалось что id должно быть строкой, а не числом

но я заодно и amount сделал строкой и все норм заработало